# unable to rerender inputfield

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I am trying to rerender an input field based on the event 'onchange' specific other input field which is of type multiselect picklist.

vf page

```
<apex:inputField value="{!MyObject__c.myField__c}">
<apex:actionSupport action="{!myMethod}" rerender="idToRender" event="onchange"/>
</apex:inputField>
<apex:inputField id="idToRender" value="{!MyObject__c.toBeRenderedField__c}" rendered="{!myBool}"/>
```

apex class

```
myMethod()
{
myBool = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<apex:inputField id="idToRender" value="{!MyObject__c.toBeRenderedField__c}" rendered="{!myBool}"/>`

Instead of this you need to do this

```
<apex:outputpanel  id="idToRender">
<apex:inputField value="{!MyObject__c.toBeRenderedField__c}" rendered="{!myBool}"/>

</apex:outputpanel >
```

Because when first time page load this `inputfield` is `rendered= false` so it is not available on page so you can't `rerender` it. In that case we need to `rerender` the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

`<apex:actionSupport action="{!myMethod}" rerender="idToRender" event="onchange"/>`

unless you also have a function that returns the string 'idToRender'